# Pandas Equivalent for SQL window function and rows range

Tags: pandas, google-bigquery, range, window-functions

Consider the minimal example

```
customer   day  purchase
Joe        1       5
Joe        1      10
Joe        2       5
Joe        2       5       
Joe        4      10
Joe        7       5
```

In BigQuery, one would do something similar to this to get how much the customer spent in the last 2 days for every day:

```
SELECT customer, day
, sum(purchase) OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY day ASC RANGE between 2 preceding and 1 preceding)
FROM table
```

What would be the equivalent in pandas? i.e., expected outcome

```
customer   day  purchase    amount_last_2d
Joe        1       5             null  -- spent days [-,-]
Joe        1      10             null  -- spent days [-,-]
Joe        2       5               15  -- spent days [-,1]
Joe        2       5               15  -- spent days [-,1]
Joe        4      10               10  -- spent days [2,3]
Joe        7       5                0  -- spent days [5,6]
```

Comment: can you post expected output?

Comment: I think you should add a row with day=3 to your input and output to provide a better unit test for possible solutions. I worry your current example will allow for solutions that can relplicate your output, but not your desired logic.

Comment: That's one of the points - the RANGE function operates over the day values, not the row numbers (e.g. the sum in the two previous days, not in the 2 preceding rows)

Comment: Which is why you should provide a more complete example. I think with your current input you can attract answers that seem to work for this case, but not in others. That’s why it’s important to have a simple example that can discern between answers that implement your desired logic, and those that are close but only work for this specific example.

Comment: I see your point ALollz, modified the example so the purpose is clarified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `groupby` with `shift` then `reindex` back

```
df['new'] = df.groupby(['customer','day']).purchase.sum().shift().reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df[['customer','day']])).values
df
Out[259]: 
  customer  day  purchase   new
0      Joe    1         5   NaN
1      Joe    1        10   NaN
2      Joe    2        10  15.0
3      Joe    2         5  15.0
4      Joe    4        10  15.0
```

Update

```
s = df.groupby(['customer','day']).apply(lambda x : df.loc[df.customer.isin(x['customer'].tolist()) & (df.day.isin(x['day']-1)|df.day.isin(x['day']-2)),'purchase'].sum())
df['new'] = s.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df[['customer','day']])).values
df
Out[271]: 
  customer  day  purchase  new
0      Joe    1         5    0
1      Joe    1        10    0
2      Joe    2         5   15
3      Joe    2         5   15
4      Joe    4        10   10
5      Joe    7         5    0
```

Comment: thanks Beny, it's a good idea but I think that would work to retrieve the previous recorded day amount, but not the sum over an arbitrary lagged time window. I modified the example to clarify the purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the right way to go, and this is limited since only one customer is provided; if there were different customers, I would use `merge` instead of `map`; Note also that there is also an implicit assumption that the days are ordered in ascending already:

Get the purchase sum based on the groupby combination of `customer` and `day` and create a mapping between `day` and the sum:

```
sum_purchase = (df.groupby(["customer", "day"])
                 .purchase
                 .sum()
                 .shift()
                 .droplevel(0))
```

Again, for multiple customers, I would not drop the `customer` index, and instead use a merge below:

Get a mapping of the days with the difference between the days:

```
diff_2_days = (df.drop_duplicates("day")[["day"]]
                 .set_index("day", drop=False)
                 .diff()
                 .day)
```

Create the new column by mapping the above values to the day column, then use `np.where` to get columns where the diff is less than or equal to 2:

```
(
    df.assign(
        diff_2_days = df.day.map(diff_2_days),
        sum_purchase = df.day.map(sum_purchase),
        final=lambda df: np.where(df.diff_2_days.le(2), 
                                  df.sum_purchase, 
                                  np.nan))
      .drop(columns=["sum_purchase", "diff_2_days"])
)


    customer    day     purchase    final
0       Joe     1             5     NaN
1       Joe     1            10     NaN
2       Joe     2             5     15.0
3       Joe     2             5     15.0
4       Joe     4            10     10.0
5       Joe     7             5     NaN
```

Ran your code in postgres to get an idea of what range does and how it differs from rows; quite insightful. I think for windows functions, SQL got this covered and easily too.

SO, let me know where this falls on its face, and I'll gladly have a rejig at it.